# Conditional update of MongoDB documents using Spark

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I have documents within MongoDB which have the following structure:

```
_id:63d7cc8c30f3fddc1d4a266b
name: "nameA"
adress: "Paris"
timestamp: "2023-04-17 16:43:00"
```

On the other hand, I have a Spark DataFrame which has data with the following structure:

```
+-----+------+-------------------+
|name |adress|timestamp          |
+-----+------+-------------------+
|nameA|Berlin|2023-04-15 12:23:00|
|nameA|London|2023-04-18 09:54:00|
+-----+--------------------------+
```

To perform a simple update in MongoDB with Spark, we use the following function:

```
df.write
  .format("mongodb")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .option(MongoConfig.CONNECTION_STRING_CONFIG, ConfigMongoDb.getUri(configMongoDb))
  .option(MongoConfig.DATABASE_NAME_CONFIG, configMongoDb.database)
  .option(MongoConfig.COLLECTION_NAME_CONFIG, collection)
  .save
```

But the objective is to update the MongoDB document based on the `name` key but on the condition that the timestamp of the DataFrame is greater than the timestamp contained in the MongoDB document.

Compared to the examples given above, the result in MongoDB would be:

```
_id:63d7cc8c30f3fddc1d4a266b
name: "nameA"
address: "London"
timestamp: "2023-04-18 09:54:00"
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **idFieldList** and **upsertDocument** option to write operation. After adding these to the function it will look like in pyspark

```
df.write
  .format("mongodb")
  .mode("append")
  .option("idFieldList", "name")
  .option("upsertDocument", True)
  .save
```

Please Note - Include all your mongodb options too